# How to handle null while comparing maps using streams - Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 data structures with values like:

```
List<Map<String,String>> customerDirectory
```

```
[{NAME=ALEX BENSON, PHONE=012-12342, ADDRESS=123 MAIN ST, CITY=QUEENS, STATE=NY},
 {NAME=ZOYE ABEL, PHONE=012-12445, ADDRESS=123 WATERSIDE, CITY=WINDSOR, STATE=CT}]
```

and

```
Map<String,String> customerInfo
```

```
{NAME=ALEX BENSON, PHONE=012-12342, ADDRESS=123 MAIN ST}
```

I am trying to iterate through the `customerDirectory` to find if `customerInfo` has exact match in values for the keys - `"NAME","PHONE","ADDRESS"` so that I could find if the record is a duplicate.

So I have come up with:

```
List<String> compareKeys = Arrays.asList("NAME","PHONE","ADDRESS");

Function<Map<String,String>, String> getVal = mp -> compareKeys.stream().map(mp::get).map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.joining());

BiPredicate<Map<String,String>, Map<String,String>> checkDup = (mp1,mp2) -> getVal.apply(mp1).equals(getVal.apply(mp2));

boolean anyMatch = customerDirectory.stream().anyMatch(customer-> checkDup.test(customerInfo, customer));
```

But the `customerInfo` map can have value for `ADDRESS` as `null` for which I have tried:

```
BiFunction<Map<String, String>, String, String> handleNull = (mp, key) -> mp.get(key) == null ? " " : mp.get(key);
```

and I have used it in :

```
Function<Map<String,String>, String> getVal = mp -> compareKeys.stream().map(key->handleNull.apply(mp,key)).map(mp::get).map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

But I still end up getting `NullPointerException` which means I am missing the exact flow probably.
Is there a better way to handle `null` values here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in a better way I think.

```
boolean anyMatch = customerDirectory.stream()
         .anyMatch(m -> m.entrySet().stream()
           .filter(entry -> compareKeys.contains(entry.getKey()))
           .allMatch(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(customerInfo.get(entry.getKey()))));
```

or even more concise:

```
 boolean anyMatch =
            customerDirectory.stream()
                   .anyMatch(m -> compareKeys.stream()
                            .allMatch(key -> m.get(key).equals(customerInfo.get(key))));
```

Comment: won't this give NullPointer for customerInfo ADDRESS value when it is null like I have mentioned in the question?

Comment: 2nd solution is better, without filtering

Comment: Yeah this is surely better but not working for map when {ADDRESS=null}, Tried to add filter after compareKeys.stream() but still getting NullPointer.

Comment: which _Map_ do you mean? see [demo](https://ideone.com/hO1Jlc)

Comment: Correct, the filter I was adding was causing problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

If i correctly understood your question then you just want to find out is there any exact match or not, and you want to keep your answer in **anyMatch.** Please try to update your code with below one.

```
Function<Map<String, String>, String> getVal = mp -> 
    compareKeys.stream().map(mp::get).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(String::trim)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
```